# multiple parameters in webservice in ios

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, web-services, ipad

I would like to know whether passing multiple parameters while consuming webservice for an iPad application will have any impact in performance. I mean, will it take more time when the request and response have more number of parameters?. I have few less important parameters in webservice methods. I'm not sure whether to remove them or not. please guide me..

Comment: two key metrics here: 1) number of bytes - not number of params - will be a factor in request time, 2) how good of a contributor you are to SO will be a factor in how much effort others expend on your behalf.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes the no of parameter seems to have no impact in performance. We added few more parameters later and the time taken request and response does not change. Thanks once again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What matters is not the number of parameters it's the size of the payload. One can have a Web service method with only one parameter and have a payload ranging from a few bytes to ten, hundreds or mega bytes and this is what affects performances.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes the no of parameter seems to have no impact in performance. We added few more parameters later and the time taken request and response does not change. Thanks once again.